# C++ : destructors not being called

Tags: c++, function, constructor, destructor, new-operator

In the below code all the constructors are called and the result is as expected, but the Destructor is not being called after the "for" loop finishes. Can anyone please state the reason?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Animal
{
    private:
        string name;

    public:
        Animal(){cout << "Constructor called" << endl;}
        ~Animal(){cout << "Destructor called" << endl;}
        void set_name(string name){this-> name =name;}
        void call_name (){cout << "the letter typed is : " << name <<endl;}
};

int main(){

    char c_t_car = 'A';

    Animal *pDog = new Animal[26];

    for(int i = 0; i <= 26; i++)
    {
        string s_t_name (1, c_t_car);
        pDog[i].set_name(s_t_name);
        pDog[i].call_name();
        c_t_car++;
    }

    delete[] pDog;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you see a `<=` in a `for` loop, as in , `for(int i = 0; i <= 26; i++)` Check closely. All too often this is a bug.

Answer (score 4):

[The output I get says "Segmentation fault"](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b436a2cd54894046), i.e. it crashes.

Apparently this crash happens before the destructor has a chance to run.

That's probably because you loop up to *and including* 26, which is the 27th element. But your array only has 26 elements. So you destroy your memory.

It's likely that you meant to write `for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)`, not `<=`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a <= but you start at 0. change that to <.

Edit: To catch segmentation violations faster use a debugger like gdb.
compile with a -g flag and and type in the console

```
gdb program
run
```

This will execute the program until segmentation fault. Then you need to backtrace.

```
bt
```

this will show a stack frame. select the frame where the error occurred.

```
f #number
```

It will then show local info on which line the error was thrown. Now you can print print local info by hitting p and the name of the variable

```
p i
```

this will show you that the iterator i was greater than the max index of the container.